# internet explorer dont cut overflowed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I'm confused about the overflow handling in IE while using [jquery tree pluigin](https://github.com/daredevel/jquery-tree).
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- start tree configuration -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://144.76.39.211/scripts/jquery.tree.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://144.76.39.211/scripts/jquery.tree.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        div#tree {
            font-size: 75%;
            border: 1px solid Gray;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;                
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $("#tree").tree();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>A<ul>
                <li>Alabama</li>
                <li>Alaska</li>
                <li>Arizona</li>
                <li>Arkansas</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>C<ul>
                <li>Colorado</li>
                <li>Connecticut</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>D<ul>
                <li>Delaware</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>F<ul>
                <li>Florida</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>G<ul>
                <li>Georgia</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>H<ul>
                <li>Hawaii</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>I<ul>
                <li>Idaho </li>
                <li>Illinois</li>
                <li>Indiana</li>
                <li>Iowa  </li>
            </ul></li>
                <li>K<ul>
                <li>Kalifornien</li>
                <li>Kansas</li>
                <li>Kentucky</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>L<ul>
                <li>Louisiana</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>M<ul>
                <li>Maine </li>
                <li>Maryland</li>
                <li>Massachusetts</li>
                <li>Michigan</li>
                <li>Minnesota</li>
                <li>Mississippi</li>
                <li>Missouri</li>
                <li>Montana</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>N<ul>
                <li>Nebraska</li>
                <li>Nevada</li>
                <li>New Hampshire</li>
                <li>New Jersey</li>
                <li>New Mexico</li>
                <li>New York</li>
                <li>North Carolina</li>
                <li>North Dakota</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>O<ul>
                <li>Ohio  </li>
                <li>Oklahoma</li>
                <li>Oregon</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>P<ul>
                <li>Pennsylvania</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>R<ul>
                <li>Rhode Island</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>S<ul>
                <li>South Carolina</li>
                <li>South Dakota</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>T<ul>
                <li>Tennessee</li>
                <li>Texas </li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>U<ul>
                <li>Utah  </li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>V<ul>
                <li>Vermont</li>
                <li>Virginia</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>W<ul>
                <li>Washington</li>
                <li>West Virginia</li>
                <li>Wisconsin</li>
                <li>Wyoming</li>
            </ul></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

That's works in Firefox31, but looks weird in IE11. The 'ul' flows over the bottom of the 'div', but it shows a scrollbar. This effect is only visible, if the 'tree' done his work. Without this, all functionality is fine!

I tried an example in JSFiddle ([look here](http://jsfiddle.net/70vgnnfv/2/)), but this looks fine in both browsers. So I have NO idea, what to do.

So my question is: 
How can I get the clipping of the div content while using the tree-plugin working every time and every browser, without juggling with complicated hacks or tweaks of CSS and Javascript?

PS: I'm a noob in CSS and the most results I get is by Copy&Paste or Try&Error.
PSS: Excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is using `overflow-y: scroll;` for the box instead of auto. That way the content should scroll the way you desire.

In my understanding, auto will just do whatever the browser has decided is right, while if you specifically tell it to scroll when overflown on the y-axis, it is forced to do so in all browsers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for late response... thx for answer, try it with success!